# $_FILES returning nothing

Tags: php, mysql, file

So, I recently looked up how to upload files onto a database using Blob. This is the tutorial I found http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

I followed this tutorial and came up with this code -

HTML FORM -

```
                <form action='memberPage.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <input type='text' name='programName' placeholder='Program Name'></input>
                <input type='text' name='programPrice' placeholder='Price'></input>
                <div id='uploadFiles'>
                    <input name='userfile1' type='file' onchange='addAnother()'>
                </div>
                <input type='submit' value='Create program' style='cursor:pointer;'></input>
            </form>
```

PHP UPLOAD ($programName is specified outside code it looks something like $programName=$_POST["programName"];)

```
            for($i = 1; $i < 999;$i++){
                if(isset($_POST["userfile" . $i]) && $_FILES["userfile" . $i]['size'] > 0){
                    $Filename = $_FILES["userfile" . $i]['name'];
                    $finfo = new finfo();
                    $Filetype = $finfo->file($_FILES["userfile" . $i]['tmp_name'], FILEINFO_MIME);
                    $Filesize = $_FILES["userfile" . $i]['size'];
                    $Filetmpname = $_FILES["userfile" . $i]['tmp_name'];
                    $Fileerror = $_FILES["userfile" . $i]['error'];


                    $fp      = fopen($Filetmpname, 'r');
                    $content = fread($fp, filesize($Filetmpname));
                    $content = addslashes($content);
                    fclose($fp);


                    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                    {
                        $Filename = addslashes($Filename);
                    }

                    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO upload(name,type,size,content,program) VALUES('
                    '" . $Filename. "','" . $Filetype. "','" . $Filesize . "','" . $content . "','" . $programName . "')");


                }else{
                    $i=999;
                    header("location:memberPage.php");
                }
            }
```

But when I submit the forum, the files return with nothing in them, no name, and the size is zero.

I have also checked out the other question things on here and did not find the answer, so my guess is that it is in my code.

Let me also specify that the onchange='addAnother()' adds another input, but has the next end number on it (Example - userfile1, it would then add userfile2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to check file element istead of post element.

Try changing this

```
if(isset($_POST["userfile" . $i]) && $_FILES["userfile" . $i]['size'] > 0){
```

to this

```
if(isset($_FILES["userfile" . $i]) && $_FILES["userfile" . $i]['size'] > 0){
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually, thanks! a part of my code was incorrect and you were right! THANKS :D.

Answer (score 2):

you are using input name "programName" and try to get "Programname" the same with $_POST.

PHP is case sensitive you should use same case in PHP "$_POST['programName']"

Comment: Sorry, that was my own typo in the post. Thanks for catching it, I have that part correct in the code but I accidently wrote Programname in the text above.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to create the input names as arrays.

```
 <input name='userfile[]' type='file' onchange='addAnother()'>
```

and iterate through it in php like:

```
if (isset($_FILES["userfile"]) && is_array($_FILES["userfile"])) {
    for ($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["userfile"]);$i++) {
        echo $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$i];
    }
}
```